# Automatically deriving type class constraints using GADTs

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, algebraic-data-types, gadt

I'm writing a library to deal with infinite sequences using lazy evaluation. For brevity I'm using Generalized Algebraic Data Types (GADTs) to assert an `Ord` constraint on the index of each term in the sequence. Hence the following typechecks:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Term ix cff where
  Term :: (Ord ix) => ix -> cff -> Term ix cff

data Sequence ix cff where
  Seq :: [Term ix cff] -> Sequence ix cff

f (Seq (Term i x:_)) (Seq (Term j y:_)) = i < j

{-
add :: Sequence ix cff -> Sequence ix cff -> Sequence ix cff
add (Seq tms1) (Seq tms2) = Seq (addAlong (<) tms1 tms2)
    where addAlong :: (ix -> ix -> Bool) ->
                      [Term ix cff] -> [Term ix cff] -> [Term ix cff]
          addAlong ord (Term i x : tms1) (Term j y : tms2) = []
-}
```

As expected, GHCi tells me that `f :: Sequence t t1 -> Sequence t t2 -> Bool`. Doing the comparison `i < j` requires an `Ord` instance, but that is taken care of by the constraint `(Ord ix)` in the definition of `Term`.

However, when the lower block is uncommented, the `add` function fails to typecheck with the error ``` No instance for (Ord ix) arising from the use of ``<'' ```. Shouldn't it be able to figure out `(Ord ix)` from the `Term ix cff` that appears in the definition of `Sequence`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Terms bound to a function argument are by default monomorphic (aka rank-0 polymorphic), because Haskell98 only supports rank-1 polymorphism, and a polymorphic argument makes a function rank-2 polymorphic.

Hence, in `Seq (addAlong (<) tms1 tms2)`, the compiler can only consider `<` as a monomorphic comparison on the rigid type `ix`. To consider `<` as a monomorphic function the compiler needs to resolve the `Ord` instance. However, at that point the `Ord ix` instance is not available, since it can only be matched out of a `Term`!

The solution that's closest to your original code is to explicitly make `addAlong` rank-2 polymorphic:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, UnicodeSyntax #-}

add :: Sequence ix cff -> Sequence ix cff -> Sequence ix cff
add (Seq tms1) (Seq tms2) = Seq (addAlong (<) tms1 tms2)
    where addAlong :: (∀ ix' . Ord ix' -> ix' -> Bool) ->
                      [Term ix cff] -> [Term ix cff] -> [Term ix cff]
          addAlong ord (Term i x : tms1) (Term j y : tms2) = []
```

This way, `<` is simply passed as it is (as a polymorphic `Ord => ...` method), hence the compiler doesn't need to have the instance available at `Seq (addAlong (<) tms1 tms2)` but can resolve it later when you have `Term`s available.

You should of course consider whether you really need that. Keeping an `Ord` dictionary in each `Term` seems rather wasteful to me – the problem wouldn't turn up if you kept the constraint in `Seq` instead:

```
data Term ix cff where Term :: ix -> cff -> Term ix cff

data Sequence ix cff where
  Seq :: Ord ix => [Term ix cff] -> Sequence ix cff

add :: Sequence ix cff -> Sequence ix cff -> Sequence ix cff
add (Seq tms1) (Seq tms2) = Seq (addAlong (<) tms1 tms2)
    where addAlong :: (ix -> ix -> Bool) ->
                      [Term ix cff] -> [Term ix cff] -> [Term ix cff]
          addAlong ord (Term i x : tms1) (Term j y : tms2) = []
```

Comment: In the first `add`, I think `∀ ix' . ix' -> ix' -> Bool` should be `∀ ix' . Ord ix' => ix' -> ix' -> Bool`. Further, the second `add` should require `ScopedTypeVariables` and `add :: forall ix.  ...` otherwise the `ix` in `addAlong :: (ix -> ...` is not the same.